# Help me identify this fly species?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, taxonomy

I found this fly in **Bengaluru/India**. It was larger than usual flies. It was more than 1cm in size, with black color which has blue shades in it. I managed to take just this one pic, then it flew away.

[image]

Comment: Based on the numerous strong bristles visible on the abdomen I suspect family Tachinidae; I don't know the Indian fauna, so I can't go any deeper.

Comment: yeah, you might be right ...